# Container and algorithms

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java at the moment and I'm trying to do it by implementing my own container classes. My question is:
If I've implemented let's say three different container classes and I do want to have the ability to sort each of them in three different ways, so I have:

```
Container_one with sort_1, sort_2, sort_3  
Container_two with sort_1, sort_2, sort_3  
Container_three with sort_1, sort_2, sort_3
```

where sort_1, sort_2 and sort_3 are identicall algorithms in every container (but they're different to each other), is there a way to implement them just once and then reuse them in other containers or do I have to implement them every time I'm implementing new container?
Thanks.

Comment: sort what and how? please be specific and if possible, give an example or a scenario.

Comment: sort elements stored in those containers, how is unspecified, just pick any three sorting algorithms. This is just to get the idea how to organize my container classes and those algorithms.

Comment: The `Strategy Pattern` might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3):

One way to separate algorithms from data structures on which they operate is by thinking of the operations that you need in order to implement your algorithm, abstract these operations out as an interface, code up your algorithm in terms of the interface, and have all data structures implement the interface.

For example, let's say that your sorting algorithm needs a way to compare items at positions `i` and `j`, and a way to swap items `i` and `j`. Then your interface would look like this:

```
interface Sortable {
    int compare(int i, int j);
    void swap(int i, int j);
}
```

Now you can implement your sorters in terms of `Sortable`:

```
void sort1(Sortable container) {
    // first way to sort
}

void sort2(Sortable container) {
    // second way to sort
}
```

Finally, you make your containers implement `Sortable`:

```
class CoolContainer1 implements Sortable {
    public int compare(int i, int j) {
        ...
    }
    public void swap(int i, int j) {
        ...
    }
    // other operations
}

class CoolContainer2 implements Sortable {
    public int compare(int i, int j) {
        ...
    }
    public void swap(int i, int j) {
        ...
    }
    // other operations
}
```

Note that all the above is simply a suggestion for your learning exercise. Java provides powerful sorting facilities that work on lists and arrays, and let you specify your sorting order to the smallest possible detail. Take a loop at the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method for more information.

Comment: #dasblinkenlight, if I understand correctly in each of those container classes I need to implement compare and swap, am I right?

Comment: @DonRoby You're right, that's `Collections.sort`! Thanks, I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting algorithms should be externalized to three `Sorter` classes or static `sort(Container)` methods, and take the container to sort as argument. If the containers all implement a common interface, you can use the same algorithm to sort all of them.

The common interface should just contain methods to get the size of the container, get an element at a given index, and set an element at a given index. This is sufficient to be able to sort a container.

Or it could have two methods: one that provides an array containing all the elements of the container, and one which reinitialize it with all the elements of a (sorted) array.

You're reimplementing `java.util.List` and `java.util.Collections.sort()`;

Answer (score 0):

Separate the algorithm from the container. For example:

```
interface SortAlgorithm { ... }

class Sort1 implements SortAlgorithm { ... }
```

Then you parameterize each Container with the sort algorithm:

```
class Container1 { public Container(SorthAlgorithm alg) {...} ... }

aContainer = new Container1(new Sort1())
```

Take a look into the [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) hierarchy of the Java library.

Each sortable collection can be parameterized with the logic used to compare items ([Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)).

Usually the "sort algorithm" (not the comparison method), is tightly coupled with the internal structure of your collection (ie a balanced tree), that's why it makes more sense to "share" the comparison method and not the whole sort algorithm.